# What is the Use of "NSNumber numberWithInt" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnumber

i'm retrieving data from  server - where the NS Number used contains BOOL value in database format. but when i try to use TRUE or FALSE , it doest allow to do. 
- i'm a Beginner of Xcode.

```
for (unsigned int i =0; i<studentDashBoardDetails.count; i++) {

            // Early CheckOut Days
    if ([[[ studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"dayType"]isEqualToString: @"Working"]&&[[[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"isAttended"]isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]&&[[[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"timeSpent"]isLessThan:@"08.00.00"])
        {
            NSLog(@" Early Check out on   %@",[[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"attendanceDate"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber numberWithInt` returns the signed `integer` for the current value, to access bool values you can use `NSNumber numberWithBool` method, it creates an object and returns `NSNumber` which can be treated as a `bool`.

I hope it will help you in achieving proper way on how to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

While saving save as `NSNumber` like this

```
    NSNumber *isAttended = [[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"isAttended"];
```

and while reading it do your condition like this

```
if (isAttended.boolValue){
    //true
}else{
   //false
}
```

in your case you have to do like this

```
if ([[[ studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"dayType"]isEqualToString: @"Working"] && isAttended.boolValue &&[[[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"timeSpent"]isLessThan:@"08.00.00"])
        {
            NSLog(@" Early Check out on   %@",[[studentDashBoardDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"attendanceDate"]);
}
```